# Where to store attachments for the Android application?

Tags: android

I am writing the application (kind of simple CRM) where user should be able to append attachments to the manually created notes. The note has the form of a simple text, the attachment could be or PDF, or a photo created by the user, or possibly any other reasonable document in future.

The application uses the SQLite database via `ContentProvider`. The content of the database should be synchronized with the central server via web services.

I am thinking about the database table dedicated to the attachments. This way, the attachments will be added to the notes via keys to the attachment table. When synchronizing with the central server, the table can be synchronized separately from other database parts of the application.

**Now the question:** How the attachments should be stored by the application? Say, the photos should probably be stored separately from the Gallery. Also the PDF documents should be stored in the disk space that is related to the application (say the security reasons). Should the attachments database table store only references to the documents, or should I consider SQLite blobs? Or is it reasonable to give user a choice to tell where the attachments are to be stored? (I mean internal storage vs. external storage [microSD card].) What pro's and con's should I expect in the cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android guidlines say that you should only store about one mb in the internal memory while you can store almost everything on the sd card. But remember that all apps with the permission to write on the sdcard can read it, so you should encrypt the data.

Starting with android 4.4 you could also use the external cache directory which should been protected. However on rooted devices this would also not protected the data.

Comment: Sorry for my bad in terminology. I have meant *internal storage* vs. *external storage*, not the *memory* in the sense of RAM. To go straight to wha I am concerned: Would you use blob for storing a file content or would you prefer the classic file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with blob in this context. I would store encrypted filed.

Comment: I mean SQLite blob type in the sense that the content of the file is stored as bytes in that data type of the SQLite database, i.e. not directly in the file system. I have mentioned *security*, but actually, I do not need encryption. The application need not be that much secure. I just want to keep the data in the application space.

Comment: I would never store binary data in a database. What I mean about internal the memory that you should not store there much data.

Comment: No that internal memory in /data/data/your.package.name

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48656/discussion-between-pepr-and-rekire)